# Aligning equation in align environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I would like to fit the column and bring the equation to the left with equally spaced 'or'. Any suggestions how to go from here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    &&&&&&&&    (3x-2)(2x^{2}-13x+15)&=0 &&  \\
            &&&&&&&&        (3x-2)(2x-15)(x+1)&=0  && \color{blue} 
 {\text{Factor the trinomial}}\\
3x-2&=0 &&\text{or} & 2x-15&=0 &&\text{or} & x+1&=0 && \color{blue} 
{\text{Set each factor to zero}} \\
                  3x&=2 &&\text{or} &  2x&=15 &&\text{or} &  x&=-1  && 
 \color{blue}{\text{Solve}}\\
                                        x&=\dfrac{2}{3} &&\text{or} &   
x&=\dfrac{15}{2} &&  &  &  && \color{blue}{\text{}}\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    &&&&&&&&    \makebox[0pt][r]{$(3x-2)(2x^{2}-13x+15)$}&=0 &&  \\
            &&&&&&&&        \makebox[0pt][r]{$(3x-2)(2x-15)(x+1)$}&=0  && \color{blue} 
 {\text{Factor the trinomial}}\\
3x-2&=0 &&\text{or} & 2x-15&=0 &&\text{or} & x+1&=0 && \color{blue} 
{\text{Set each factor to zero}} \\
                  3x&=2 &&\text{or} &  2x&=15 &&\text{or} &  x&=-1  && 
 \color{blue}{\text{Solve}}\\
                                        x&=\dfrac{2}{3} &&\text{or} &   
x&=\dfrac{15}{2} &&  &  &  && \color{blue}{\text{}}\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I didn't know those commands. Thanks for saving me time!